# Setting up bazel as an environment variable windows

Tags: windows, bazel

I've been trying to use bazel on Windows 10 Pro, and I was following the instructions located at https://docs.bazel.build/versions/3.7.0/install-windows.html

I found the place to add user-specific and system-wide environment variables, and I added the path to `bazel.exe` and called the variable `bazel`, but when I try to type `bazel` into a command prompt window, it still isn't recognized.

Let me know if you need any more detail to help answer my question, I'm confused where I'm going wrong.

[image: bazel set as environment variable]

[image: not recognizing bazel]

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have to add the bazel binary path to your 'path' environment variable.
So search for Edit system environment variables -> Advanced -> Environment variables

and then under System Variables -> path -> edit  you can add the path of your bazel bin (C:\User\Panda\Documents) and it should work.  Detailed description with screenshots it's  here: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `bazel` as a *command*, not as an *environment variable*. When you want to use the value of an environment variable, you need to surround the name in `%`s, ie:

`C:\Users\Panda>%bazel% version`

**UPDATE**: otherwise, since the `.exe` file you want to execute is also named `bazel`, it can be executed as a *command*, you would just need to add the path to `bazel.exe`'s installation folder (`C:\Users\Panda\Documents`) to your system's `%PATH%` environment instead <sup>1</sup>, as [@Fed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65870250/65863) explained, and then you can execute `bazel` normally:

`C:\Users\Panda>bazel version`

<sup>1: I don't recommend installing apps in your user profile's `Documents` folder! You should create a new folder for installing `bazel` into, preferably under `C:\Program Files` (64bit) or `C:\Program Files (x86)` (32bit). Then you can add `%ProgramFiles%\bazel\` to your `%PATH%` environment.</sup>

Comment: Thank you this fixed it for me! Is there any shortcut to make it so I don't have to always add the %'s?

Comment: Do what Fed's answer says. Add the location of the *folder* that holds `bazel.exe` to the `%PATH%` environment, don't create a new environment variable that points to `bazel.exe` itself.

Answer (score 0):

so, to make it work, all you need is :

1. download bazel [link to the bazel releases](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases), place file somewhere (let's use 'D:\tools\bazel' as example)  and rename it from 'bazel_nojdk-7.0.0-pre.20230628.2-windows-arm64.exe
   ' to 'bazel' from whatever it is
2. Right-click on 'My Computer' or 'This PC' icon.
3. Select Properties from the drop down menu.
4. Select 'Advanced' tab. advances tab screenshot
5. Click on the Environment Variables button.
6. Locate System Variables area
7. Select 'Path' variable
8. Click on Edit button.
9. Click  New button.
10. Paste the path to the GeckoDriver folder. ('D:\tools\bazel')
11. doublecheck you did everything right :
12. Open console (cmd.exe)
13. type bazel
14. in case path was added successfully you will see this :
    [cmd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTY8E.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  How is your answer different from the other answers already provided? It seems you just break it down into a more verbose level of detail. Theres already an equivalent answer.

Comment: Your answer doesnt appear to add anything that hasn't been provided already